# Uniform Distribution Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be the sample such that $X_i = e^{\xi}$, where $\xi$ has a uniform distribution on the segment $[0, \theta]$. Need to find maximum likelihood estimation.
My attempt:
I found density $p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{x\theta}, x \in [1, e^{\theta}]$. But counting $L(x1, ..., x_n, \theta)$ i got $L(x1, ..., x_n, \theta) = ln(\frac{1}{\theta^nx_1x_2...x_n}\mathbb{I}\left\{min(X_1, ..., X_n) \geq 1\right\}\mathbb{I}\left\{max(X_1, ..., X_n) \leq e^{\theta}\right\})$. But how to find maximum of the fuction, which depends on 2 indicators?

Comment: Please note that the support of $X$ depends on the parameter $\theta$. So it is the same for the likelihood function. Use indicator function to express the density if you are not familiar with this yet.

Comment: @BGM completely forgot to write indicator function while computing likehood function. Thank you for important note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\theta$ does not appear in the first indicator, we are basically reduce to find $\theta$ maximizing $g\colon\theta\mapsto \theta^{-n}\mathbf{1}_{A\leqslant e^\theta}$ for some $A$ (in your context, $A=\max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$). Since $\exp$ is increasing, we can rewrite $g$ as
$g(\theta)=\theta^{-n}\mathbf{1}_{\ln A\leqslant \theta}$.
The function $g$ vanishes on $\left(-\infty,\ln A\right)$ and is decreasing on $\left[\ln A,\infty\right)$ hence the maximum is reached as $\ln A$.